# Django UpdateView does not Upload ImageField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-generic-views

I don't get any errors.
Ok who sees the mistake? because I don't. here is my code:

Views.py:

```
class UpdateFeaturete(generic.UpdateView):
    template_name = 'images/updatefeaturete.html'
    model = FeatureteImage
    fields = ['header', 'body', 'image']

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(FeatureteImage, pk=self.kwargs['f_pk'])

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super(UpdateFeaturete, self).form_valid(form)
```

models.py:

```
class FeatureteImage(models.Model):
    park = models.ForeignKey(Park)
    header = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='featureteimages')

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    park = Park.objects.get(id=self.venue.id)
    if park.featurete >= 3:
        pass
    else:
        park.featurete += 1
        park.save()
        super(FeatureteImage, self).save(*args, **kwargs) 


def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('park-features', kwargs={'pk': self.park.pk,})
```

my template:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Save Changes." class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

Everything seems to be working properly. All the fields seem to update except the ImageField. 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah okay, so what you need is not the **save** method you need to override the **clean** method:

```
def clean(self):
    park = Park.objects.get(id=self.venue.id)
    if park.featurete >= 3:
        raise ValidationError('error message goes here')
```

Comment: Nope. the problem is in my model. I have overwritten the default save function so that nobody is allowed to have more than 3 featuretes. so if I have 3 and i want to update one it still gives me an error. (see the code I updated)

Comment: try to put `super(FeatureteImage, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` outside the __else__ block, so it saves always the data

Comment: that doesn't work because it still saves it even when there are 3 featuretes

Comment: Ah okay, so what you need is not the __save__ method you need to override the __clean__ method.

  `def clean(self):
        park = Park.objects.get(id=self.venue.id)
        if park.featurete >= 3:
             raise ValidationError('error message goes here')`

Answer (score 2):

There is a duplicate error of the function `get_absolute_url()` in the code. I just tested your codes and it is working very well even Images are getting uploaded.Please find the reason in other part.

Can you edit your post and add code for `settings.py`.

Comment: I have not included the default save function I created in my models. That is the problem. Because I have 3 featuretes and it just passes. any suggestions on how to tackle that one?